# Travelling salesman problem with maximum day length and start/end day at a specific node

Tags: mathematical-optimization, minizinc

The Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP) is stated as follows:

- Let a directed graph G = (V, E) be given, where V = {1, ..., n} is a set of nodes, E <= V x V is a set of arcs.
- Let also each arc e = (i,j) be assigned a number c[i,j], which is the length of the arc e.
- The problem is to find a closed path of minimal length going through each node of G exactly once.

Some additional constraints/modifications to the problem:

- The “salesman” starts and ends at the same node (say node 1) each day.
- The salesman can work up to a maximum of a 10 hour day.
- Once the salesman arrives at a node, they must perform some work, the amount of work will vary between 1-4 hours for each node. No work needs to be done at the start/end node (node 1).
- The salesman can travel through the same node more than once, but any repeated node visit will not require any additional work (i.e. salesman just travels through node on the way to the next). Based on the geography of the nodes, it will be highly likely that the salesman will travel through a node multiple times.

Can anyone point me to existing solutions to this problem? Preferably in MiniZinc (I recently completed the coursera course), but can probably interpret a python solution too.

Answer (score 0):

[TSP in AMPL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3c52.png)

This is the version I use, it"s written in AMPL(an other mathematical language), you can easly transform it to minizinc,
and add the additionnal constraint